# How to create a GA segment for all users who did not complete an event on the website?

Tags: google-analytics, advanced-segments

I want to analyze the behavior flow for all the users who did not complete the events I have created using Tag Manager. I am not sure which conditions to use while creating the segment.

Answer (score 3):

When creating your segment, go to the **Conditions** section on the left-hand side.

For **Filter**, select *Users* instead of Sessions and choose *Exclude*.

Now, select either *Event Action*, *Event Label* or *Event Category*, whichever is appropriate, and select the appropriate event.

[image: Screenshot of Image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check for no events actioned, then you'd want to use Behaviour > Total Events = 0. If you want to check for exclusion for a number of events, you'll want to have a series of "And" conditions to ensure that Event Label does not exactly match your excluded events.